# A database for logs that can be used operationally

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, logging

I am currently working on a B2B platform on which I have to implement a feature where the respective customers should be able to download their logging entries up to 2 years ago.
There can be up to 1 million logging entries per day per customer. Now this is quite a lot of data, but it is retrieved on average 5-6 times a month per customer. This means that a lot of data is stored, but relatively little of it needs to be retrieved.

We host on AWS and as the main database we currently use Postgres, which can of course handle this, but I ask myself if there aren't more suitable candidates.
I also had cloudwatch in mind, but I don't know if you should use it operationally for these purposes.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Periodically export data as partitioned parquet to S3 and use Athena to retrieve it, that should be orders of magnitude cheaper than using a database to hold all data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the log database I work on - [VictoriaLogs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/VictoriaLogs/) - for this task in the following way:

1. To write logs from every customer in a separate [log stream](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/VictoriaLogs/keyConcepts.html#stream-fields) or a separate [tenant](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/VictoriaLogs/#multitenancy).
2. To query the needed logs by specifying the needed time range via [_time filters](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/VictoriaLogs/LogsQL.html#time-filter).

VictoriaLogs returns the queried logs in streaming manner as soon as they are found. It returns all the requested logs, even if their number exceeds a billion. This means it is OK to query and read billions of logs for a particular customer on a particular time range without worrying about resource usage at VictoriaLogs side.

VictoriaLogs also provides the following benefits over other databases for logs:

- Low resource usage. For example, it uses 30x less RAM, and 15x less disk space than ElasticSearch on the same production workload.
- Fast full-text search over all the log fields.
- Zero tuning and configuration for optimal performance.
- Good integration with command-line tools for automated or manual log analysis - head, less, awk, sort, etc. See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/VictoriaLogs/querying/#command-line).